# Why is $*$ defined only for homotopy classes, and not individual paths between points?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Why is the operation $*$ well-defined on **homotopy classes**, and not all continuous paths from $[0,1]$ to $X$ in general?

I suppose "well-defined" means that if $a=b$ and $c=d$, then $a*c=b*d$. I feel this is valid for individual paths between points too. Why homotopy classes? What about non-homotopic paths?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "what about non-homotopic paths"?

Comment: Small typo: you mean "if $a=b$ and $c=d$ then $a*c=b*d$". I'm assuming you mean loops and not paths, and $*$ is the operation that says "do one loop and then the other", but maybe this is wrong...if you do mean this, then the operation is well-defined on paths, essentially automatically, because two paths are "equal" only when they are exactly the same. The more interesting statement is that it is well-defined on homotopy classes, because now some quite different looking paths are considered equal.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft- I meant what about paths between $x$ and $y$ which are not homotopic? Why would they be considered distinct?

Comment: I still don't quite follow. Do you mean why do we not wish to identify paths with each other unless they are homotopic?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft- Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: So if we were to identify even more paths, which extra ones should those be? Clearly if we identify too many we end up with something trivial. It turns out that identifying homotopic paths leads to getting a group structure, which can be a powerful thing to get, and it also turns out that this group is not too small, so we really are able to recover information about the space from the group.

Comment: It looks like you have at least three unregistered accounts, all named "algebraically_speaking". I suggest that you stick to one account to better keep track of your questions. You can also register and subsequently merge your accounts. You might have to ask one of the moderators at this site to merge them, I'm not sure. As far as I know, you are also prevented to upvote or accept answers to your questions unless you register.

Answer (score 4):

The usual path concatenation is well defined on paths whose end points match up - that is, we can evaluate $f*g$ if and only if $f(1)=g(0)$.

As to why we want to consider path concatenation as an operation on *homotopy classes* of loops (paths whose both end points are equal to the base point of the space $X$) when defining the fundamental group, or on homotopy classes of all paths when defining the fundamental groupoid, this is so that we get the corresponding structure. For instance, any non-constant loop concatenated with its inverse loop (the loop where you go the other way round) is **not** equal to the constant loop at the base point, however it is *homotopic* to the constant loop at the base point, and so path concatenation on homotopy classes gives us a group structure (we also need to consider homotopy classes in order to get associativity and existence of identities).

Comment: We can get around the problem of associativity and identities by using Moore paths instead. But to get inverses we really need _some_ notion homotopy.

Comment: It is also possible to get a groupoid algebraically by taking the category of  Moore paths $(r,f)$ and adding the relations which make  sure that $-(r,f)$ becomes the inverse of $(r,f)$.  I don't know of any use of this construction!